# PostgreSQL recursividad o Array-Loop, como convertir hijos en padres y padres en hijos?

Tags: sql, array, postgresql, bucles, recursión

Hola a todos espero y me puedan ayudar, estoy trabajando con postgresql 13 y tengo que hacer una function que al recibir la siguiente información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se inserta en una tabla, una vez insertada cada uno de los valores de destino se transforma en origen y el origen toma el lugar del destino y se inserta en la tabla hasta que se recorren todos los valores del destino quedando de la siguiente forma:

**Destino 2 se convierte en origen:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Destino 4 se convierte en origen:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Destino 6 se convierte en origen:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya estuve viendo opciones con arreglos en algún loop o recursividad y no encuentro la forma de resolver el problema, les agradecería muchísimo si alguien me pudiera orientar o dar algunos ejemplos.

Answer (score 0):

Quizas está query te sirva o te de una idea de como lo puedes resolver.

Por lo que entiendo para cada destino en tu tabla tienes que generar n filas (una por cada fila existente), donde el nuevo origen es el destino anterior combinado con cada uno de los destinos existentes, pero si el origen coinicide con el destino (es él mismo) entonces lo reemplazas por el origen original.

En la siguiente query he realizado un CROSS JOIN con la misma tabla (todos las filas emparejadas con todas las filas):

```
SELECT 
       t1.destino AS origen, 
       CASE WHEN t1.destino = t2.destino THEN t1.origen ELSE t2.destino END AS destino, 
       t2.sort
FROM t AS t1
CROSS JOIN t AS t2
ORDER BY origen, destino;
```

Salida:

Como puedes ver la columna sort no coincide con el resultado que esperas (en algunos casos), yo lo tomé del sort de la query pero se podrían ordenar las filas y luego recalcular el sort.

| origen | destino | sort |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | 6 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 6 | 3 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 4 | 2 |

De esta forma podes calcular la columna sort para cada origen y ordenando por el destino, pero no estoy seguro de que calcularlo así sea lo que deseas.

```
SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY origen ORDER BY destino) AS sort

FROM (
   SELECT 
       t1.destino AS origen, 
       CASE WHEN t1.destino = t2.destino THEN t1.origen ELSE t2.destino END AS destino

   FROM t AS t1
   CROSS JOIN t AS t2) AS aux
ORDER BY origen, destino;
```